# SOAP Java 1.4.2

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

What libraries are available to write a SOAP client in Java version 1.4.2?

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) runs on Java 1.4 and has fairly good support for specs like WS-Security.

Answer (score 1):

The two major options are Apache [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/)/[Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) and the Sun [Metro JAX-WS stack](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) (included in J2EE 5 and J2SE 6).

However, Metro is Java 5 and newer only, as it uses annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Metro nor CXF will work with Java 1.4.x, they both require Java5.   I think the only options are Axis/Axis2 and XFire, but even Axis2 1.5 is going to be Java 5 only and XFire is pretty much replaced by CXF.   Java 1.4 is pretty much a dead end for WebServices stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the common ones were around then; you're likely to need to go to archived versions though, as that's several major revisions old now.  Java 5 in particular added enough goodness that its features tended to be adopted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Apache CXF. Here's a tutorial on the different ways to develop a web service client:

http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html