# Java 1.3 Websphere 5 application -> need call SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2 web service

Tags: java, websphere, webservice-client

I have old application that works in Websphere 5 with Java 1.3. 
I cannot change Java version or app server version.

I need to add to this application code that will call web service. 
AFAIK target web service supports both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2.

Unfortunately I have only little experience with WS clients. Some time ago I wrote WS client using Java 5. It was very simple, I used wsimport tool that generated all necessary classes from WSDL.

But, as I understand, Java 1.3 and Websphere 5 doesn't have such possibility. Words like JAX-WS and JAXB  are related to the latest java versions.

Could someone please provide me with some guide (or just advise :)) what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions though I haven't tried them out:

1. [Look into Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#ConsumingWebServicesWithAxis) and try
   out the tutorials
2. Read a [similar
   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863808/soap-java-1-4-2) for more suggestions in
   case the first one doesn't work out

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere 5 does not support Axis. If you have related WebSphere Studio you can easily create SOAP client using wizard. Maybe WebSphere 5 have command line tool like wsimport

Comment: But what if I add axis jars to WebSphere 5? I need only WS client, not service

Comment: it's hard to guess, because it was in year 2003. I remember that some problems was with class loader and different web service implementation. Of course, you can try, and maybe get a good result.